# CSS animations in Opera and IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, load

Recently I have launched [CSSload.net - CSS spinners and bars generator](http://cssload.net). The animations work perfectly in Firefox and Webkit browsers. Does anyone know if there is anyway to animate elements like this in Opera and IE?

Comment: jQuery, on which these are based, is designed to work across browsers. Are you sure they don't work?

Comment: Great site! For IE, try making sure the page is rendered in IE9 mode. You can do that by either forcing it with a Metatag, or making the DOCTYPE html (rather than what you have now). Usually works for me.

Comment: now, it works on Opera, btw, great tool!

Answer (score 1):

IE10 will support CSS3 animations without prefixes so the vendor prefix for IE is not needed for any code, even for backwards compatibility, since IE9 never supported it.

Answer (score 0):

for progressive enhancement, add the real style property, example, you have -moz-transition,-webkit-transition...add transition too. 
for opera, add their prefix, -o- to everything that is -moz and -webkit.
for ie, you can use css sandpaper, but its relying on a javascript fix http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/04/05/cross-browser-animated-css-transforms-even-in-ie/  if you want pure css, you could always add filters for IE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx
here's a great example of adding filters for IE http://robertnyman.com/css3/css-transitions/css-transitions-mac-os-x-stacks.html

i'm not sure if there is an -ms-transition. i want to say there is, but not finding anything atm